# My Invoice and LineItem table aren't outputting? They are just blank with no values. Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
       --Insert Invoice And SaleItem
    BEGIN TRY
   BEGIN TRANSACTION
     DECLARE @CustomerID INT
  SET @CustomerID = (SELECT CustomerID FROM tblCustomer WHERE Name = 'Larry Bond' AND Phone = '2286562989')

   DECLARE @SalesID INT
   SET @SalesID = (SELECT SalesID FROM tblSalesPerson WHERE FName = 'Larry')


     INSERT INTO tblInvoice (DATE,Subtotal, Salestax,Total, ShipDate, ShipHand, CustomerID, SalesID)
      VALUES ('2010-8-6', '174.44', '1.44','186.87', '2010-8-6', '10.99', @CustomerID, @SalesID),
       ('2010-8-7', '34.44', '5.44','50.87', '2010-8-6', '10.99', @CustomerID, @SalesID),
       ('2010-8-8', '140.44', '5.44','156.87', '2010-8-6', '10.99', @CustomerID, @SalesID),
       ('2010-8-9', '74.23', '1.44','86.86', '2010-8-6', '10.99', @CustomerID, @SalesID)

      --Retrieve the newly created primary key to insert as a foreign key in tblLineItem
     DECLARE @InvoiceID INT
    DECLARE @ItemID INT

    SET @InvoiceID = @@Identity

    --Retrieve primary key of product for current listitem
    --Insert new row in tblLineItem
   SET @ItemID = (SELECT ItemID FROM tblItem WHERE Description ='Go Jag T Shirts - Color Red – Size M')

   INSERT INTO tblLineItem ( Quantity, Amount, UnitPrice, InvoiceID, ItemID)
   VALUES ('6', '52.66', '4.99', @InvoiceID, @ItemID)

     SET @ItemID = (SELECT ItemID FROM tblItem WHERE Description ='Jag Spirit Towels- Color White')
    INSERT INTO tblLineItem ( Quantity, Amount, UnitPrice, InvoiceID, ItemID)  
     VALUES ('4', '23.89', '1.25', @InvoiceID, @ItemID)

      SET @ItemID = (SELECT ItemID FROM tblItem WHERE Description ='Go Jag Red T- Size XL')
       INSERT INTO tblLineItem ( Quantity, Amount, UnitPrice, InvoiceID, ItemID)  
      VALUES      ('5', '42.89', '4.99', @InvoiceID, @ItemID)

SET @ItemID = (SELECT ItemID FROM tblItem WHERE Description ='Go Jag Red T-Size L')
  INSERT INTO tblLineItem ( Quantity, Amount, UnitPrice, InvoiceID, ItemID)  
 VALUES  ('3', '6.99', '4.99', @InvoiceID, @ItemID)

     END TRY

     BEGIN CATCH
  DECLARE @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(500)
  SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' Rolledback transaction:   insertions.'
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

  END CATCH
```

My table tblCustomer,Tblitem,tblSalePerson shows its output but table invoice and lineitem doesn't why? They are just blank there is no information in them.

Comment: Better try best to improve the question formatting and remove unnecessary  code.

Comment: They always want to see all of my code

Comment: I changed it better

Answer (score 0):

Your code failed to execute because you are assign a result set to a single value variable.

Let's change

```
SET @CustomerID = (SELECT CustomerID FROM tblCustomer WHERE Name = 'Larry Bond' AND Phone = '2286562989')
```

to

```
SET @CustomerID = (SELECT TOP 1 CustomerID FROM tblCustomer WHERE Name = 'Larry Bond' AND Phone = '2286562989')
```

And similar change should be applied to

```
SET @SalesID = (SELECT SalesID FROM tblSalesPerson WHERE FName = 'Larry')
SET @ItemID = (SELECT ItemID FROM tblItem WHERE Description ='Go Jag T Shirts - Color Red – Size M')
SET @ItemID = (SELECT ItemID FROM tblItem WHERE Description ='Jag Spirit Towels- Color White')
SET @ItemID = (SELECT ItemID FROM tblItem WHERE Description ='Go Jag Red T- Size XL')
SET @ItemID = (SELECT ItemID FROM tblItem WHERE Description ='Go Jag Red T-Size L')
```

by adding `TOP 1`

Below also for your reference how you can make use of cursor to iterate the insert.

```
DECLARE @CustomerID INT

DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR   
SELECT CustomerID FROM tblCustomer WHERE Name = 'Larry Bond' AND Phone = '2286562989'

OPEN my_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor
INTO @CustomerID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN 

    -- do what you want to do with @CustomerID

END
```

Comment: When I add top 1 my customerid stays 1 and it doesn't change to 2,3,4

Comment: If you want to do batch update, avoid using single value variable. You may want to use something like `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp. Or if single variable is easier to you, consider using `CURSOR`, which may give you bad performance however.

Comment: Say if I HAVE CUSTOMER ID IN MY INVOICE TABLE HOW CAN I CREATE IT WHERE THEY CAN ADD to each value such as 1-4